# getting facebook page fans?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get a list of fans page ids from my page?
i know that using Graph API  its bug may be another way.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12880

Also its posible to get facebook session cookies?  (datr; lu; locale; L=2; act; c_user; sct; xs; presence; e; wd;)--i see this from firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fql query.

Select uid from page_fan where page_id = *****

refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/